# How do I add row programatically in TDBGrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I want to add some data in grid to show user.

I want to use `TDBGrid`

How do I add any row to grid without a database?

Thank you

Comment: Using data-aware controls like TDBGrid comes with a lot of baggage if your data isn't stored in one of Delphi's various types of TDataSet.  Use a TStringGrid instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A TDBGrid reflects the data in an underlying dataset (query, clientdataset etc). To have new or changed data appear, update the data in the dataset (and/or maybe refresh it).

If you do not use an external database, your are still able to use e.g. a `TClientDataSet` and store its data to file (proprietary format or XML, depending on your Delphi version - see its documentation). Given the flexibility of using datasets (e.g. editing the data), I recommend this.

Alternatively, use a TstringGrid and store your data in any (other) way you want.

[It also depends on what else you want to do with the data once it's presented in the grid. If you want the user to be able to edit it, `TClientDataSet` is *the* way to go.]